# Populate a Select Box with Years using PHP

Tags: php

I would like to fill a select box with year starting from 1950 to the current year. How can I achieve this using PHP? I would not like to use JavaScript for this.

```
<select><?php
     $currentYear = date('Y');
        foreach (range(1950, $currentYear) as $value) {
            echo "< option>" . $value . "</option > ";

        }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Even though this was closed 9 years ago (!!! that's a lot of years!) I did not and do not think this question is a bad one, or difficult to tell what is being asked here. It is trafficked, and has answers.

Comment: Let's reopen the question.

Comment: Is there anything not working with the given code? It does not use any JS, it prints all years between 1950 and the current one - so is there anything I don't get?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `range` to create an array containing all the required years, loop that array and print an `option` for each of the values.

You can use `date('Y')` to figure out the current year.

```
// use this to set an option as selected (ie you are pulling existing values out of the database)
$already_selected_value = 1984;
$earliest_year = 1950;

print '<select name="some_field">';
foreach (range(date('Y'), $earliest_year) as $x) {
    print '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x === $already_selected_value ? ' selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$x.'</option>';
}
print '</select>';
```

Try it here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Pw3U4O

**Documentation**

- `foreach` - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
- `range` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php
- `date` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 16):

```
<select name="select">
<?php 
   for($i = 1950 ; $i < date('Y'); $i++){
      echo "<option>$i</option>";
   }
?>
</select>
```

Something like this?

Comment: The closest to being the most efficient. Could improve by putting date('Y') into a variable.

Comment: That sort of micro-optimization would have absolutely no discernible effect, and is a fallacy. Benchmark it yourself and see.

Comment: I do not understand... When did I ever say it will have a discernible effect? When? My point is, being efficient is a good principle and not hard to achieve in this example. When you write a lot of code with snippets like this, it all adds up. How do you know OP is not writing an enterprise application?

Comment: By virtue of posting your suggestion, it is thus implied that it is worth mentioning - otherwise why post it. So, by virtue of having brought it up, you are saying that it would have a discernible effect - else why bring it up to begin with? As for the optimization itself, it is true that counting before a loop is slightly faster, but when we're dealing with such a trivial script the difference at most is 10 microseconds. Put it in to perspective. Even enterprise systems do not focus on micro-optimizations of this degree, it isn't worth the time or effort - it isn't even worth mentioning.

Comment: Just because you posted a solution which could use the same optimization, there is no need to defend it because I'm not attacking it. Writing clean & efficient code is a nice virtue. Where I work, this is encouraged.

How do you know I posted it so you notice that it will have an effect? I posted it because I follow this virtue because I want to be a better software developer.

Real-time systems, not that they would be written in PHP, need these kinds of optimizations. He is probably not writing one, but  it is still wrong to say that in all cases this level of optimizations is not needed.

Comment: Here is another variation ->  for($i = $earliest_Year ; $i <= $last_Year ; $i++){
                                                             if ( $i == $curr_Year ) { $select="selected='selected'"; } else {  $select=""; }
                                                             echo "<option $select value='$i'>$i</option>";
                                                          }    where $earliest_Year = date('Y') - 10;
$curr_Year = date('Y');
$last_Year = date('Y') + 10;

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

$starting_year  = 1950;
$ending_year    = 2011;

for($starting_year; $starting_year <= $ending_year; $starting_year++) {
    $years[] = '<option value="'.$starting_year.'">'.$starting_year.'</option>';
}

?>

<select>
    <?php echo implode("\n\r", $years);  ?>
</select>
```

Option #2:

```
<select>
<?php

foreach(range(1950, (int)date("Y")) as $year) {
    echo "\t<option value='".$year."'>".$year."</option>\n\r";
}

?>
</select>
```

Comment: ah no it doesn't just tested it myself

Comment: Withdrew my comment and vote after reading closer.

Comment: Hello, do you use ajax function in getting each value of this year array? because when I click the submit button, there is no value of year appear.